# Can SQLite optimize a starts-with query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
> create table T (ID integer primary key autoincrement, Path text not null);
> create index T_Path on T(Path);
```

I want to select all rows for which `Path` starts with `'abcd'`.

```
> explain select * from T where Path >= 'abcd' and Path < 'abce';
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     11    0                    0   Start at 11
1     OpenRead       1     4     0     k(2,,)         0   root=4 iDb=0; T_Path
2     String8        0     1     0     abcd           0   r[1]='abcd'
3     SeekGE         1     10    1     1              0   key=r[1]
4     String8        0     1     0     abce           0   r[1]='abce'
5       IdxGE          1     10    1     1              0   key=r[1]
6       IdxRowid       1     2     0                    0   r[2]=rowid
7       Column         1     0     3                    0   r[3]=T.Path
8       ResultRow      2     2     0                    0   output=r[2..3]
9     Next           1     5     0                    0
10    Halt           0     0     0                    0
11    Transaction    0     0     6     0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
12    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

Works fine. By the use of `SeekGE` we can see that an index lookup is being done. By analyzing it further we can see this is opening the index, seeking to `'abcd'`, reading rows sequentially until it gets to `abce` and then stopping. Good work, query optimizer.

But it's kinda annoying that we have to write the prefix twice. Can't SQLite do that for us?

```
> explain select * from T where substr(Path,1,4) = 'abcd';
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     11    0                    0   Start at 11
1     OpenRead       0     2     0     2              0   root=2 iDb=0; T
2     Rewind         0     10    0                    0
3       Column         0     1     2                    0   r[2]=T.Path
4       Function       6     2     1     substr(3)      0   r[1]=func(r[2..4])
5       Ne             5     9     1                    80  if r[1]!=r[5] goto 9
6       Rowid          0     6     0                    0   r[6]=rowid
7       Column         0     1     7                    0   r[7]=T.Path
8       ResultRow      6     2     0                    0   output=r[6..7]
9     Next           0     3     0                    1
10    Halt           0     0     0                    0
11    Transaction    0     0     6     0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
12    Integer        1     3     0                    0   r[3]=1
13    Integer        4     4     0                    0   r[4]=4
14    String8        0     5     0     abcd           0   r[5]='abcd'
15    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

No. It can't. This one is a full table scan.

Question: **Is there a nice way to make SQLite return rows starting with a certain string?**

`Path LIKE 'abcd%'` is not the answer - it's case insensitive, and it does a table scan for that reason.

Desired result: something like

```
select * from T where starts_with(Path, 'abcd');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is explained in [The LIKE Optimization](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_like_optimization) you can use the operators [`LIKE` or `GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_match_and_extract_operators).

For both operators, first you must make sure that the column `Path` is indexed using the built-in `BINARY` collating sequence (if no collation is mentioned in the definition of the index then the table's collation is used and if no collation is mentioned in the definition of the table either then `BINARY` is used).

For `LIKE` you must also turn on `case_sensitive_like` pragma:

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like=ON;
```

which makes `LIKE` case-sensitive.

If you don't want to change `case_sensitive_like` pragma then use `GLOB` (which is case-sensitive):

```
select * from T where Path GLOB 'abcd*';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=af61c6ab0f2644c71bb68fbe97e244ec).